# How to delete Rufus

Tags: uninstall, rufus

I just downloaded Rufus. And no longer need it. I am looking to delete it completely off my computer. I go to controlpanel > Programs > Uninstall but it's not located in the programs menu.

Any help?

Comment: Rufus is (also) offered as a portable application, meaning no installer, no uninstaller required or included.  Are you sure you didn't download and use the Portable version?  What's the name of the file you downloaded?

Comment: Just select the folder the executable is in and then delete that folder.

Comment: Sorry, a little busy. I'll answer all questions asap.

Comment: oops didn't mean to hit send. . But the Download itself under recent downloads is rufus-2.3.exe. from akeo.ie. Version 2.3.709

Comment: I voted this question back up, since it's exactly what I wanted to know the answer to!  What I really want to know is which application put this on my computer as a new user?

Comment: Rufus author here. Just select the file and delete it. Rufus does NOT come with an installer (yes, that also applied to the "non-portable" version). It's a *STANDALONE* executable, so if you see Rufus and want to get rid of it, just delete the file you see - that's all.

Answer (score 1):

open file explorer search rufus it should show up then right click then delete it will take it into recycling bin then empty it

Answer (score -2):

A couple of things seem good to do:

1) Try looking if it's available for UNINSTALL with CCleaner.  CCleaner is more aggressive in removing Registry entries associated with existing programs, and may . It's available in a free version, and has an Uninstaller as well as its cleaning sections. It's other features are useful.

2) Look and see if it's loaded upon boot, by using a tool, (assuming a Windows installation) like Windows Sysinternals "Autoruns". In Linux perhaps "Monit", or the

[Windows Sysinternals is home to a very good set of software tools and web site;   Provides as much of the details of how Windows actually works, as you will likely easily get]

This program created by Sysinternals founder Mark Russinovich (now with MSFT) allows you to deactivate these autorun programs using a check box. For Linux and Unix "Monit" appears similar.  Frankly, the Linux system and command line can provide much info on processes and how they are run.

In Windows, "Autoruns" shows each method that is used at startup to run code as a "process". It's fascinating to see the dozens of processes started by a modern computer upon boot. Often, troubling programs, which seem to be difficult to remove, are simply not set up for removal when installed, and are set to load as an autorun process upon boot up.